# Keil debugger ini file complains to user types as "undefined identifier"

Tags: c, debugging, watch, keil

I have a type which describes the data layout of the EEPROM and I'm trying to watch it in Keil debugger via a pointer to a fixed address using the following command:

```
WS 1, (EEPROM_Type*)0x1101F000
```

where `EEPROM_Type` is a packed structure type which is used in my code to access various values in EEPROM. The above debugger command works fine when I enter it manually in a debug session, but not in the debugger initialization file:

```
WS 1, (EEPROM_Type*)0x1101F000
_______^
*** error 34: undefined identifier
```

The expression `(EEPROM_Type*)0x1101F000` can also be added directly to the watch window, but it is removed from the watch window whenever a debug session is restarted. I assume this is because the same error happens internally when the list of watch expressions is processed. I would like to have it in my watch list permanently without having to add it manually every time. Is there a way to do this?

Note: none of this happens with a native C type, e.g. `(char*)0x1101F000`. This expression is correctly saved it the watch window across debug sessions, and can used with a `WS` command in the debugger ini file.

Note 2: the same thing happens with types describing the MCU internal registers, e.g. `CPU_Type`.

I'm using Keil 5.26.2, which is the last version for which I have the license. However, I would be interested to know if this issue is solved in the latest versions, since that would be yet another argument I could bring to the table the next time we are discussing license upgrades.

Comment: Since I don't have access to µVision any more, I can just assume: The time when the debugger initialization file is loaded, the debuggee is not yet loaded or parsed. Have you tried to include a load command in your debugger initialization file?

Comment: @thebusybee I just added `LOAD "D:\\Path\\to\\xxx.axf"` to the ini file, and I still get the same error. I think debug information is available even without this command, e.g. `WS 1, main` works fine (showing the address of the main function in the watch window).

Comment: Oh, well, it was at least a try. One thing I remember is that µVision was quite instable and had some errors. :-} This might be the case here, too.